# Openrowset for excel: do not convert True/False to 1/0

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm using Openrowset to import excel having a "Status" column, whose value can be "TRUE/FALSE/CANCELLED". I've set registry accordingly with TypeGuessRows=0. When the "status" column in excel file includes values of "TRUE/FALSE/CANCELLED", it is imported as text value as expected.

However here is the problem, when it includes only "TRUE/FALSE", the imported value becomes "1" and "0". So after importing several excel files, my sql table column has values of "TRUE, FALSE, CANCELLED, 1, 0". How to tell sql server always import as text without auto convert TRUE/FALSE to 1/0? I don't want to write a stupid sql statement to update 1/0 back to TRUE/FALSE. 
Any other solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs only when you have only TRUE or FALSE values in a particular file (because in that case there is no way of knowing the actual data type even after traversing all rows). (If you have headers available in the imported files, you can set **TypeGuessRows=1** to guess the datatype from the top row only)

One of the ways to fix the problem is to open Excel, select the column (with TRUE/FALSE), right-click and select "Format Cells..." from the popup menu. Under Number tab, select Text as Category. Click ok.

Another way is to update the rows immediately after insert.

Thanks.

Comment: It's bad news that MS doesn't provide official way to disable auto converting from TRUE/FALSE to 1/0. I have to set TypeGuessRows=0 as needed due to having complex excel file. 
Changing the cell's format works as a solution although it needs an extra step of re-defining the column. But it is not using "Formatting Cells...". Instead, it should use "Text to columns" under Data group and define the column as text, that make it work perfectly.